# FFmpeg Minimize memory usage or add timeout to youtube-dl

Tags: python, cmd, ffmpeg, youtube-dl

So I am using FFmpeg to download an m3u8 stream. For optimization, I tried running the FFmpeg directly instead of using youtube-dl with it. But for some reason, the ffmpeg.exe uses 140 MB of memory while ffmpeg.exe via youtube-dl uses only 14 MB of memory.

So I have two questions:

- Is there a way to minimize the direction FFmpeg memory usage
- Add a timer (custom command) to FFmpeg via youtube-dl. FFmpeg has a build-in command -t (seconds). Is there a way to use it via youtube-dl?

FFmpeg directly (140MB in memory):

```
import os
os.system('cmd /k "ffmpeg -i https://36-d4.divas.cloud/CHAN-3792/CHAN-3792_1.stream/playlist.m3u8 -t 100 output.mp4"')
```

FFmpeg using youtube-dl (14MB in memory):

```
import youtube_dl

ydl_opts = {
    'nopart': True,
    'outtmpl': 'output.mp4',
    'nocheckcertificate': True
}

with youtube_dl.YoutubeDL(ydl_opts) as ydl:
    ydl.download(['https://36-d4.divas.cloud/CHAN-3792/CHAN-3792_1.stream/playlist.m3u8'])
```

**Edit:**
I double checked and both the exe FFmpeg for the direct and `youtube-dl` are both the same version.

Comment: Does it improve the memory usage if you set `-threads 1` to limit the number of threads it's running? By default ffmpeg will use the # of cores available on your system. If you're on a common 8 core system and memory usage is a linear function of thread count, that would nearly explain the 10x difference. But I'm just guessing here, so you'll have to validate.

Comment: It actually did reduce it by a bit, but unfortunatelyonly to about 100MB memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

youtube-dl on linux with the link you provided seems to launch ffmpeg with theses arguments:

```
ffmpeg -y -loglevel verbose -headers 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.67 Safari/537.36\
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7\
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8\
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\
Accept-Language: en-us,en;q=0.5' \
 -i https://36-d4.divas.cloud/CHAN-3792/CHAN-3792_1.stream/chunklist_w70914220.m3u8 -c copy -f mp4 file:playlist-playlist.mp4.part
```

I guess if you just re-use them and add yours (`-t 100`) you should be able to get the same kind of memory usage.

You may also try with only `-c copy` and `-f mp4`, which I guess are the most relevant for the memory usage of ffmpeg.

Comment: Yes it acctualy worked. The solution to minimze the memory usage was `-c copy`

Comment: Full command `ffmpeg -i https://36-d4.divas.cloud/CHAN-3792/CHAN-3792_1.stream/chunklist_w70914220.m3u8 -c copy -t 50 output.mp4`